# Where does postfix store email?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I can't find any documentation on how postfix stores email. Where is it stored, and in what format? I'm using Ubuntu server 11

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Probably `/var/mail/[username]` or the more traditional `/var/spool/mail/[username]`

The normal format, called "mbox", uses a line that starts with "From " to indicate the start of each message - this is one reason why many email clients will change "From " in the body of the message to ">From ".  You can also configure it to use "maildir", in which `/var/mail/[username]` is a directory in which every email message is a file in that directory.

Comment: This is of course assuming that the user doesn't have `procmail` configured to do it for him instead.

Comment: It's also assuming that they haven't installed cyrus-sasl which moves things around.  We're trying to keep things simple.

Comment: I've installed postfix, both of the above paths are empty, but I can see the emails in the squirrel web interface.

Comment: @Alex Look in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` for the `mail_spool_directory` and `home_mailbox` and see which one is uncommented.Also look to see if `mailbox_transport = cyrus` is uncommented. Like I said above, cyrus does complicated things with your mail.

Answer (score 16):

For outbound mail (you didn't specify, and inbound is answered elsewhere) it is in `/var/spool/postfix`. If you look there you will find all sorts of subdirectories.

Comment: I cannot find my outbound mails inthere on my debian machine.

Comment: I cannot find my outbound mails in there on my debian machine.  This directory is used but things there are store only trensiently.  Alpine stores outbound emails in `/home/[username]/mail/sent-mail` for example.

Comment: Postfix does not store outgoing mail permanently.  Once it's off the system, it's no longer the responsibility of the MTA.  If you need a permanent copy, Bcc: yourself, or use whatever your MUA offers (like you mention for Alpine).

Comment: Yes, it's ephemeral. Take down your net connection and send an email. Then you'll see something queued up...

Comment: The files are not directly useful, though. Messages which could not be delivered are in `/var/spool/postfix/deferred` but the files are in some internal format.